# My SCSS file isnt working despite being connected and firefox developer ed showing me all properties as ok

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass

My scss file is not working, i have checked using firefox developer edition, all the files seem to be connected, to the html but the color and border properties passed arent showing up.
i have compiled the scss file using VScode Live SASS compiler and koala. doesnt seem to work either way ?

HTML file

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> <!-- displays site properly based on user's device -->

  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="./images/favicon-32x32.png">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Karla:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"> 
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Karla:ital,wght@0,300;1,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"> 
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./app/scss/style.css" type="text/css">
  <title>Frontend Mentor | Insure landing page</title>

</head>
 <body>
```

header.scss file

```
  <header class="header">
    <nav class="flex flex-jc-sb">
    <a href="/" class="header__logo">
    <img src="images/logo.svg" alt="EASYBANK">
    </a>

    <a href="#" class="header__menu">
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>

    </a>
    </nav>
  </header>




.header {

position: relative;
z-index: 1;

&__logo {

    img{

    }
}

&__menu {

    > span {
        display: block;
        width: 26px;
        height: 2px;
        // background-color: $dark-blue;
        color: $darkViolet;


    }
}
```

}

This is the style.scss file

```
 @import "variables";
@import "globals";
@import "header";
```

Comment: Does your `header.scss` file contains HTML?

Comment: no. it doesn't @ZsoltMeszaros

Comment: Is your problem solved? 